# Magento 2: CDN Implement

Tags: magento2, cdn

I am using CDN in my website but strange thing is, it's create html file with .js not getting why this come
https://abc-f88d.kxcdn.com/frontend/ab/custom/en_AU/Aalogics_CheckoutTooltip/template/group.html.js.

Comment: Can you please supply code used to impliment, this will allow us to determain you issue

Comment: @davagordon i add js advance js bundle in my store